# How to peel common commits off a branch?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I'm having a couple of branches, corresponding with abandoned or later postponed development, some of them are pure garbage. I use

```
git log master..mybranch
```

to find out what's `mybranch` all about, but the lists are usually needlessly long, since they contain also commits contained in master, just in a different order. This comes from `master` having been rebased.

When I try to rebase `mybranch` on top of master, I get conflicts caused by this reordering. Such conflicts are not worth resolving, as it takes time and leads to a result already known from `master`.

So what I need is a way to get rid of such commits in `mybranch`, so that only the important commits remains and the branch can be rebased more easily.

Comment: So I take it you couldn't get to what you want by `git rebase -i master` from `mybranch`, while just not picking the "common" commits?

Comment: My main problem was to *identify* the "common" commits. This should ideally happen mostly automatically, so that the risk of losing something useful gets minimized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `git cherry`. This generates sha1 values from the commit body rather than using the git commit id to compare commits. This makes it independent of the commit ordering. You use it to find commits which might be worth adding from one branch to another.

An example from the msysGit development tree might help. We have an old branch 'work/symlink' which may have been merged to the 'devel' branch sometime past. So:

```
pt111992@UKNML4132 /git (devel)
$ git cherry devel origin/work/symlink
+ 7fe3fde1d9b93472faeedb75bfd930825a5abe06
- aebecb0d31e4a546cf4d21d32e82cc852b6057bb
+ 1b467d086fd6601cd2feb34d59baf1e804f70acb
+ 3e735a0bfda6b91ae7cbb20c2c89818405c5bea9
+ d4db723c482ba4d2fd7539060834d231c35cdf53
```

This says there are 5 commits of interest (which we can also work out from the log output):

```
$ git  log --oneline devel..origin/work/symlink
d4db723 Place __stdcall between return value and function name
3e735a0 mingw.c: Use the O_BINARY flag to open files
1b467d0 Test for WIN32 instead of __MINGW32_
aebecb0 Define SNPRINTF_SIZE_CORR=1 for Microsoft Visual C++
7fe3fde Support UTF8<=>Unicode filename mapping
```

Thats the commits present on 'work/symlink' and not on 'devel'. The git cherry output suggests that the aebecb0 commit is already applied to 'devel' (from the leading minus) but the others might be worth looking into. We can check that this commit is only present on the work branch:

```
$ git branch --all --contains aebecb0
  remotes/origin/work/symlink
```

but we can also find the commit id it got merged into the devel branch with by searching for the commit message using `git log --crep` to see that this one was really picked into devel.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Actually, I'd need an even smarter command capable of finding sequences of commits in `mybranch` which are equivalent or similar to sequences of commits in `master` (since there were not only reordering but also commit splits and joins), but `git cherry` did most of the work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, `mybranch` merged or cherry-picked the `master` branch when it was active. Git merge algorithm being quite smart, if the other commits of `mybranch` were unrelated to changes that happened in `master`'s own development  the merge would be conflict-less.

If you have conflicts it only means that you have overlapping changes between both branches, and this is not related to the fact that `mybranch` contains some of the `master`'s changes.

Conclusion: the conflicts are not due to the reordering you're talking about; take a breathe and solve the conflicts by hand.

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong for at least some of the conflicts. But I tried `rebase` with a simple branch and it was neither as easy as you wrote nor as bad as I thought. Many of the conflicts came from commits in `master` having been split or joined (what I didn't mention in my question) and the solution was trivial: `git rebase skip`. Resolving the conflicts of the interesting commits was easy as well.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested this in a comment, but the more I read your post, the more I think you didn't try that:

When on the `mybranch` branch, use `git rebase -i master` will perform an interactive rebase, which'll effectively allow you to exclude the "redundant" commits from the rebase. This might need some manual comparing the commits to know which ones to choose and which to discard, but it could work.

Comment: Note that if there are conflicts in the merge maaartinus tried this will not remove them.

Comment: @CharlesB Depends. If he removes the "already committed in another order" commits and places all other commits in `mybranch` on top of the head of `master`, he might evade conflicts by merging on a tree that's not conflicting anymore... Though it is not necessarily feasible.

Comment: mmmh not sure, but let's wait for the OP feedback :)

Comment: My problem was how to easily identify the "already committed in another order" commits. Surprisingly, it was really easy for one the branch I rebased, because simply looking at the conflict was often enough to make me sure that it was already present in the master. So I could simply skip most commits. But still, an automated way as patthoyts suggested would be better.